# How to access node-mongodb-native error codes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongodb in my nodejs application. When a `MongoServerError` is raised inside my application, I would like to run instructions based on the `code` of the error. For example, I would like to handle the specific `NamespaceNotFound` error code.

However I could not find a way to import the list of all possible codes. The list https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/main/src/error.ts#L36 does not seem to be exposed to the users of the library.

Since the `MongoServerError` errors raised inside my application expose their `code` and the `codeName`, I would assume that those are not internals.

Of course, I would like to avoid duplicating those codes in my application.

Did I miss something ?

I would expect the list of `codes` from https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/main/src/error.ts#L36 to be exposed to the consumers of the library since they are accessible in the `MongoServerError` error raised inside the nodejs application.

**Example**

Here's an example of the error I would like to handle :

```
MongoServerError: ns not found
    at Connection.onMessage (/home/alex/nodejs-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:438:20)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/home/alex/nodejs-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:256:56)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at processIncomingData (/home/alex/nodejs-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:193:14)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/alex/nodejs-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:70:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:391:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:332:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:336:10)
    at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 26,
  codeName: 'NamespaceNotFound',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```